# Opencv not installing for python in terminal

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to install opencv in the terminal but every time I try installing it an error comes up saying `ERROR: Failed building wheel for numpy Failed to build numpy ERROR: Could not build wheels for numpy which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly`
I tried installing with `pip install opencv-python` and `pip install opencv-contrib-python`

Comment: which python version are you using?

Comment: I’m using python 3.9.5

Comment: First, uninstall all versions of python from your computer and try to install a new version again.

Answer (score 1):

Opencv apparently doesn't work well with M1 chip macs, so I advise using conda instead of venv or pip, things that showed errors with pip doesn't show in conda. For me atleast :)